# React to Messages in specific Discord Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to find how to message react in specific channel and without prefix.

Example: In channel `Suggestion`, when anyone writes a suggestion, bot reacts automatically with emoji, but only in `suggestion` channel and no other.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `client.on('message')` somewhere on your code.
Use that and just check what channel the message was sent, and from there add the reactions:

```
if(message.channel.type == "text" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "suggestion"){
    message.react("✅");
    message.react("❌");
}
```

*(You need to check if the message is from a Text Channel first, and then compare the name)*

Comment: No, you have a `;` after the if. the message.react() needs to be enclosed on curly braces, like the example i used on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id === "CHANNEL ID") {
      message.react('✅')
          .then(() => { 
              message.react('❌')
          });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === "suggestions") {
        message.react("✅");
    }
}
```